# Merging Web Application Projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web

I have 42 different web application projects in my solution, and I'd like to merge them all into a single web application. Is there a relatively painless way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has 2 types of Web projects: **Web Applications** and **Web Sites**.

Web Application projects (WAPs) are like any other project in VS: there's a .csproj or .vbproj file which contains builds settings, files that are included in the project, all that good MSBuild stuff.  If you have a bunch of these in the same language (VB/C#), it's mostly a matter of adding all of the files into one single project.  If you have separate languages, there's no way to combine them, and you'll have to either keep separate projects or port one language to the other; MSBuild only calls one compiler per project.  (You can later merge the assemblies with ILMerge, but you'll still have to combine the markup files from all projects yourself.)

Web Site projects (WSPs) are a little bit different.  As far as including file into the project, they just look at what's on the file system (whereas MSBuild based projects basically just have a whitelist of included files).  Also, because WSPs are not compiled by MSBuild, it is possible to mix separate languages in a single project, but you'll have to configure this yourself (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366714.aspx for a walkthrough on how it works).

Assuming you are dealing with just WAPs of a common language and you're just trying to reduce the number of projects to maintain, I can't think of a much better strategy than to just start adding existing files into the consolidated project.  You may encounter any of these issues:

1. Each separate projects behaves like its own IIS Application.  This is important for anything that either relies the /bin folder (i.e. any code), or uses the `~/` URI to refer to content within that project.  This will prevent you from just creating a folder within your MasterProject for each of the sub apps being moved.  There really isn't a good design in VS to work around this, except to have separate projects (obviously not meeting your needs...).  So, you'll likely have to add the files into the same root folder.
2. Any duplicate file names will have to be sorted out.  Or, with web.config, you may have to merge file content.
3. Ditto for any conflicting class names. Although I'm hoping that if you have much overlap, it's mostly refactored into a separate library anyways.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to clarify. I realize I can't mix languages, that is a good point.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question of how to merge the projects